# No sign problem in quantum Monte carlo simulations of 1D systems?

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, simulations

I've heard many times people saying that there is no sign problem in the quantum Monte Carlo simulations of 1D locally interacting quantum systems. I think this means, for any 1D locally-interacting Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$, there exists a "simple enough" unitary transformation $\hat{U}$ such that the transformed Hamiltonian $\hat{H}'=\hat{U}\hat{H}\hat{U}^\dagger$ has no positive off-diagonal elements, so that the partition function $Z=\mathrm{Tr}[e^{-\beta \hat{H}'}]$ can be written as the partition function of a locally-interacting classical statistical model to be simulated by Monte Carlo. Is this really true? How to prove it in general? [Note that we can restrict ourselves to 1D spin models, since 1D fermionic systems can be transformed into spin chains by the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation).]

Comment: This sounds incorrect. Are you perhaps restricting to nearest-neighbor Hamiltonians? Longer-range couplings can introduce frustration.

Comment: @RubenVerresen To clarify, by "locally-interacting" I mean finite-range interactions. We can assume nearest-neighbor interactions without loss of generality.